# Find Min/Max Values from List grouped by Object Identifier

Tags: javascript, list, max, min

I'm trying to find the largest and smallest value in an group of items with same attributes. For example from the screenshot, the max value for crop: 18157 would be 1.77 and the smallest 1.68

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kf3qhsge/

```
var myCrops = new Object();

for(i=0;i<crops.length;i++){
    if(crops[i]==crops[i+1]){
        var c = crops[i];
        var n = values[i];
        myCrops[i] = {"crop":c,"value":n};
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: `if(crops[i]==crops[i+1]){` why?

Comment: what is your expected output? Is that like `{crop: 18157, min: 1.68, max: 1.77 }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simpler in both time and space complexity than the other solutions* here:

```js
var crops  = [18002, 18154, 18154, 18155, 18155, 18155, 18156, 18156, 18156, 18156, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18176, 18176, 18176, 18176, 18176];
var values = [1.69, 1.65, 1.75, 1.7, 1.7, 1.78, 1.69, 1.62, 1.75, 1.74, 1.7, 1.72, 1.68, 1.77, 1.7, 1.62, 1.74, 1.69, 1.82, 1.68, 1.64, 1.66, 1.74, 1.57, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.66, 1.72, 1.47, 1.52, 1.7, 1.63, 1.67, 1.69, 1.7, 1.51, 1.49, 1.58, 1.63, 1.66, 1.68, 1.39, 1.71, 1.61, 1.62, 1.41, 1.52, 1.46, 1.41, 1.61, 1.65, 1.36, 1.59, 1.65, 1.64, 1.72, 1.52, 1.35, 1.49, 1.65, 1.32, 1.37, 1.69, 1.62, 1.63, 1.7, 1.72, 1.7, 1.3, 1.47, 1.56, 1.5, 1.67, 1.41, 1.73, 1.71, 1.67, 1.58, 1.73, 1.56, 1.66, 1.73, 1.57, 1.69, 1.58, 1.73, 1.47, 1.7, 1.8, 1.61, 1.77, 1.79, 1.63, 1.56, 1.58, 1.59, 1.84, 1.64, 1.77, 1.63, 1.7, 1.76, 1.73, 1.83, 1.63, 1.44, 1.32, 1.74, 1.46, 1.57, 1.67, 1.4, 1.64, 1.69, 1.58, 1.76, 1.69, 1.58, 1.72, 1.43, 1.7, 1.34, 1.69, 1.64, 1.6, 1.68, 1.5, 1.69, 1.5, 1.76, 1.47, 1.7, 1.63, 1.49, 1.48, 1.15, 1.59, 1.65, 1.6, 1.46, 1.43, 1.52, 1.55, 1.63, 1.41, 1.66, 1.62, 1.66, 1.66, 1.68, 1.63, 1.66, 1.59, 1.34, 1.67, 1.68, 1.46, 1.66, 1.77, 1.71, 1.71, 1.6, 1.47, 1.71, 1.75, 1.6, 1.58, 1.35, 1.72, 1.77, 1.68, 1.64, 1.71, 1.59, 1.63, 1.74, 1.39, 1.59, 1.71, 1.72, 1.25, 1.65, 1.7, 1.67, 1.71, 1.67, 1.49, 1.69, 1.36, 1.53, 1.73, 1.57, 1.58, 1.7, 1.61, 1.61, 1.7, 1.62, 1.69];

var myCrops = {};
for (i = 0; i < crops.length; i++) {
    
    var c = crops[i];
    if (c in myCrops) {

        var v = myCrops[c];

        if (values[i] > v.max)
            myCrops[c].max = values[i];
        if (values[i] < v.min)
            myCrops[c].min = values[i];
    }
    else {
        myCrops[c] = { min: values[i], max: values[i] };
    } 
}


console.log("Min/Max for crop 18157:\n", myCrops[18157]);

console.log("Min/Max for all crops:\n", myCrops);
```

Outputs for `myCrops[18157]`:

> {min: 1.68, max: 1.77}

- There were other solutions here when I posted this which were not as efficient, and were deleted by the posters after I posted.  Ironically before they deleted their answers they downvoted mine.

Comment: code snippet does sweet fanny albert - so why make it a code snippet

Comment: @RandyCasburn What are you talking about?  This is exactly what the OP is asking about.  I gave example of crop 18157.

Comment: @RandyCasburn My code was correct.  My snippet editing needed work.

Comment: No need to defend, I've removed my downvote. Thanks for editing and making a great answer.

Comment: @isapir - assumption much

Comment: Thank you @isapir, this is what I was looking for. The solution is very simple to understand. Thanks everyone for providing different solutions.

Comment: Great to hear @JuanVargas - I'm happy I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Here idea is

- Loop through crops and use it as key for `op` object.
- For each value of `crops` we check whether the key is already in `op` object or not if it is already there we change the max and min value based on conditions.
- If it is not than we add a new key with proper values.

```js
var crops  = [18002, 18154, 18154, 18155, 18155, 18155, 18156, 18156, 18156, 18156, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18176, 18176, 18176, 18176, 18176];
var values = [1.69, 1.65, 1.75, 1.7, 1.7, 1.78, 1.69, 1.62, 1.75, 1.74, 1.7, 1.72, 1.68, 1.77, 1.7, 1.62, 1.74, 1.69, 1.82, 1.68, 1.64, 1.66, 1.74, 1.57, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.66, 1.72, 1.47, 1.52, 1.7, 1.63, 1.67, 1.69, 1.7, 1.51, 1.49, 1.58, 1.63, 1.66, 1.68, 1.39, 1.71, 1.61, 1.62, 1.41, 1.52, 1.46, 1.41, 1.61, 1.65, 1.36, 1.59, 1.65, 1.64, 1.72, 1.52, 1.35, 1.49, 1.65, 1.32, 1.37, 1.69, 1.62, 1.63, 1.7, 1.72, 1.7, 1.3, 1.47, 1.56, 1.5, 1.67, 1.41, 1.73, 1.71, 1.67, 1.58, 1.73, 1.56, 1.66, 1.73, 1.57, 1.69, 1.58, 1.73, 1.47, 1.7, 1.8, 1.61, 1.77, 1.79, 1.63, 1.56, 1.58, 1.59, 1.84, 1.64, 1.77, 1.63, 1.7, 1.76, 1.73, 1.83, 1.63, 1.44, 1.32, 1.74, 1.46, 1.57, 1.67, 1.4, 1.64, 1.69, 1.58, 1.76, 1.69, 1.58, 1.72, 1.43, 1.7, 1.34, 1.69, 1.64, 1.6, 1.68, 1.5, 1.69, 1.5, 1.76, 1.47, 1.7, 1.63, 1.49, 1.48, 1.15, 1.59, 1.65, 1.6, 1.46, 1.43, 1.52, 1.55, 1.63, 1.41, 1.66, 1.62, 1.66, 1.66, 1.68, 1.63, 1.66, 1.59, 1.34, 1.67, 1.68, 1.46, 1.66, 1.77, 1.71, 1.71, 1.6, 1.47, 1.71, 1.75, 1.6, 1.58, 1.35, 1.72, 1.77, 1.68, 1.64, 1.71, 1.59, 1.63, 1.74, 1.39, 1.59, 1.71, 1.72, 1.25, 1.65, 1.7, 1.67, 1.71, 1.67, 1.49, 1.69, 1.36, 1.53, 1.73, 1.57, 1.58, 1.7, 1.61, 1.61, 1.7, 1.62, 1.69];

let op = crops.reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
  let min = op[inp] && op[inp].min
  let max = op[inp] && op[inp].max
  let value = values[index]
  if(op[inp]){
    op[inp].min = value < min ? value : min
    op[inp].max = value > max ? value : max
  } else {
    op[inp] = {crop:inp,min:value,max:value}
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thank you @code-maniac, this gives me the result I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

We can divide the task in two steps:
1. obtain the values corresponding to a certain crop
2. obtain the minimum and maximum among those values.

For the first step, you can filter the `values` array by looking in the corresponding index in the `crops` array. For this, we profit that the function passed to `filter` admits the index as second parameter.
For the second one, an alternative to `reduce` is to use the built-in `Math.min` / `Math.max` functions.

Namely:

```
var crops = [18002, 18154, 18154, 18155, 18155, 18155, 18156, 18156, 18156, 18156, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18176, 18176, 18176, 18176, 18176];
var values = [1.69, 1.65, 1.75, 1.7, 1.7, 1.78, 1.69, 1.62, 1.75, 1.74, 1.7, 1.72, 1.68, 1.77, 1.7, 1.62, 1.74, 1.69, 1.82, 1.68, 1.64, 1.66, 1.74, 1.57, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.66, 1.72, 1.47, 1.52, 1.7, 1.63, 1.67, 1.69, 1.7, 1.51, 1.49, 1.58, 1.63, 1.66, 1.68, 1.39, 1.71, 1.61, 1.62, 1.41, 1.52, 1.46, 1.41, 1.61, 1.65, 1.36, 1.59, 1.65, 1.64, 1.72, 1.52, 1.35, 1.49, 1.65, 1.32, 1.37, 1.69, 1.62, 1.63, 1.7, 1.72, 1.7, 1.3, 1.47, 1.56, 1.5, 1.67, 1.41, 1.73, 1.71, 1.67, 1.58, 1.73, 1.56, 1.66, 1.73, 1.57, 1.69, 1.58, 1.73, 1.47, 1.7, 1.8, 1.61, 1.77, 1.79, 1.63, 1.56, 1.58, 1.59, 1.84, 1.64, 1.77, 1.63, 1.7, 1.76, 1.73, 1.83, 1.63, 1.44, 1.32, 1.74, 1.46, 1.57, 1.67, 1.4, 1.64, 1.69, 1.58, 1.76, 1.69, 1.58, 1.72, 1.43, 1.7, 1.34, 1.69, 1.64, 1.6, 1.68, 1.5, 1.69, 1.5, 1.76, 1.47, 1.7, 1.63, 1.49, 1.48, 1.15, 1.59, 1.65, 1.6, 1.46, 1.43, 1.52, 1.55, 1.63, 1.41, 1.66, 1.62, 1.66, 1.66, 1.68, 1.63, 1.66, 1.59, 1.34, 1.67, 1.68, 1.46, 1.66, 1.77, 1.71, 1.71, 1.6, 1.47, 1.71, 1.75, 1.6, 1.58, 1.35, 1.72, 1.77, 1.68, 1.64, 1.71, 1.59, 1.63, 1.74, 1.39, 1.59, 1.71, 1.72, 1.25, 1.65, 1.7, 1.67, 1.71, 1.67, 1.49, 1.69, 1.36, 1.53, 1.73, 1.57, 1.58, 1.7, 1.61, 1.61, 1.7, 1.62, 1.69];

function extremeValues(crop) {
    const cropValues = values.filter((value, ix) => crops[ix] === crop)
    return {min: Math.min(...cropValues), max: Math.max(...cropValues)}
}

console.log(extremeValues(18157))
```

the "three-dot" notation is needed to transform an array into a list of argument for the variable-argument-count `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions.

An alternative to "three-dot" is to use the `lodash` library:

```
const _ = require("lodash")

var crops = [18002, 18154, 18154, 18155, 18155, 18155, 18156, 18156, 18156, 18156, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18157, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18158, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18159, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18160, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18161, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18162, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18163, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18164, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18165, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18166, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18167, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18168, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18169, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18171, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18172, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18173, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18174, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18175, 18176, 18176, 18176, 18176, 18176];
var values = [1.69, 1.65, 1.75, 1.7, 1.7, 1.78, 1.69, 1.62, 1.75, 1.74, 1.7, 1.72, 1.68, 1.77, 1.7, 1.62, 1.74, 1.69, 1.82, 1.68, 1.64, 1.66, 1.74, 1.57, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.66, 1.72, 1.47, 1.52, 1.7, 1.63, 1.67, 1.69, 1.7, 1.51, 1.49, 1.58, 1.63, 1.66, 1.68, 1.39, 1.71, 1.61, 1.62, 1.41, 1.52, 1.46, 1.41, 1.61, 1.65, 1.36, 1.59, 1.65, 1.64, 1.72, 1.52, 1.35, 1.49, 1.65, 1.32, 1.37, 1.69, 1.62, 1.63, 1.7, 1.72, 1.7, 1.3, 1.47, 1.56, 1.5, 1.67, 1.41, 1.73, 1.71, 1.67, 1.58, 1.73, 1.56, 1.66, 1.73, 1.57, 1.69, 1.58, 1.73, 1.47, 1.7, 1.8, 1.61, 1.77, 1.79, 1.63, 1.56, 1.58, 1.59, 1.84, 1.64, 1.77, 1.63, 1.7, 1.76, 1.73, 1.83, 1.63, 1.44, 1.32, 1.74, 1.46, 1.57, 1.67, 1.4, 1.64, 1.69, 1.58, 1.76, 1.69, 1.58, 1.72, 1.43, 1.7, 1.34, 1.69, 1.64, 1.6, 1.68, 1.5, 1.69, 1.5, 1.76, 1.47, 1.7, 1.63, 1.49, 1.48, 1.15, 1.59, 1.65, 1.6, 1.46, 1.43, 1.52, 1.55, 1.63, 1.41, 1.66, 1.62, 1.66, 1.66, 1.68, 1.63, 1.66, 1.59, 1.34, 1.67, 1.68, 1.46, 1.66, 1.77, 1.71, 1.71, 1.6, 1.47, 1.71, 1.75, 1.6, 1.58, 1.35, 1.72, 1.77, 1.68, 1.64, 1.71, 1.59, 1.63, 1.74, 1.39, 1.59, 1.71, 1.72, 1.25, 1.65, 1.7, 1.67, 1.71, 1.67, 1.49, 1.69, 1.36, 1.53, 1.73, 1.57, 1.58, 1.7, 1.61, 1.61, 1.7, 1.62, 1.69];

function extremeValues(crop) {
    const cropValues = values.filter((value, ix) => crops[ix] === crop)
    return {min: _.min(cropValues), max: _.max(cropValues)}
}
```

Of course, you need to incorporate the `lodash` library in order to have the latter option working.

Hope it helps - Carlos